# Algebra 2 Optimization Problem - Find the minimum fencing required

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

You are designing a garden that will be enclosed by fencing on three sides and by a house on the fourth side. You want the area of the garden to be 288 square feet, but you want to minimize the amount of fencing used. How many feet of fencing do you need? The question asks to be solved by finding the minimum of a parabola, not the Lagrange method/function.

Comment: I want to inform you that MSE is not a homework solving website.

Comment: The website does say that any question, of any difficulty can be asked. I can quote it if you want.

Comment: I have read it myself but the reason this website is not a homework solving website is because homework is given for one's own benefit. When you ask someone to solve it all you are doing is simply copying off the answer. Whom does this type of activity harm? Your teacher? The answerer? Or you?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/a-consolidated-homework-policy?rq=1

Comment: I understand your point, but our teacher told us to research the problem on our own during winter break. She never taught it herself.

Comment: _Exactly_. She told you to research it _on your own_. Posting a question online does not seem to be doing it on your own. I normally would not have been so pissed off but the line "Please show all work" really enraged me. The teacher gave you this question to test your ability. Simply copying does not seem to showcase your ability. Matin I believe you are better than any of those incompetent students who take part in such acts! Try yourself. If it does not happen then there is no problem. It is not like your teacher will not explain, is it?

Answer (score 2):

the amount of fencing is given by $$u=2a+b$$ the area of the garden is $$A=ab$$
solving this for $b$ and plug this in the formula for $u$ we get
$$u=2a+\frac{A}{a}$$ Can you proceed?
using the $AM-GM$ inequality we get
$$2a+\frac{A}{2a}\geq 2\sqrt{2a\cdot \frac{A}{2a}}=2\sqrt{2A}$$

Comment: I really, really want to thank you for not giving the entire solution!

Comment: I still want you to know, Mohammad, that we were supposed to learn it OURSELVES. This was a sample problem I found on the internet to learn optimization better myself.

Comment: i have added some lines for you! happy new Year!

Comment: @MatinNawabi in that case talk to the school authorities. Teaching is a noble profession and only a great teacher can produce great students.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $x$ and $y$ are the sides of your garden, you know $xy=A=288\,\text{ft}^2$, and you want to minimise $x+2y$. Because $y=\frac{A}{x}$, you can substitute:

$$x+2y=x+\frac{2A}{x}=M$$

where $M$ is as-yet-unknown minimum. Multiply by $x$:

$$x^2-Mx+2A=0$$

*This* is the parabola you need to analyse. For an $M$, does it have a solution for $x$? What is the smallest such $M$? Once you find that $M$, what are $x$ and $y$?